# multipart form-data not working properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, multipart

In My JSP page I have three seperating forms with enctype ="multipart/form-data". On each of these forms I am uploading a file.
The first form is uploading the file correctly with type as application/pdf. But, the remaining two forms uploading the files as application/octet-stream. 
The code as follows

```
    <div id="form1" class="category-form" style="display:none;">     
    <form id="form" action="UploadServlet?action=form1" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="bottom fit" vertical layout>  
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
           <input id="file" name="file" type="file" data-placeholder="Attach file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-info">    
       </div>

     </div>
    </form>
    </div>

         <div id="form2" class="category-form" style="display:none;">    
    <form id="form" action="UploadServlet?action=form2" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="bottom fit" vertical layout>  
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
           <input id="file" name="file" type="file" data-placeholder="Attach file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-info">    
       </div>

     </div>
    </form>
    </div>


         <div id="form3" class="category-form" style="display:none;">    
    <form id="form" action="UploadServlet?action=form3" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="bottom fit" vertical layout>  
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
           <input id="file" name="file" type="file" data-placeholder="Attach file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-info">    
       </div>

     </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My Servlet code as

```
           @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
           public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet 
            {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, res);
    }

     @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
            if(action.equals("form1"))
              {
                  Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

                    if (filePart != null) 
                     {
                         System.out.println("File Parts Not Null");
                         System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                         System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                         System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
                         System.out.println("File name is : "+filename);

                         inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
                      }
                 }
                 if(action.equals("form2"))
              {
                  Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

                    if (filePart != null) 
                     {
                         System.out.println("File Parts Not Null");
                         System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                         System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                         System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
                         System.out.println("File name is : "+filename);

                         inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
                      }
                 }
```

Comment: Maybe because there are 3 forms with same id: `form id="form"`. I'm not sure but I am almost certain that it doesn't work properly

Comment: @Hugo Thank you for your reply, I changed form id's but it still shows the file type AS  application/octet-stream AND SIZE AS 0.

Comment: I am guessing the the content is being sent via Javascript / jquery - if so please add that code to your question

Comment: What about `input id="file"`? There are also 3 of them. Usually many elements with same id make things don't work

Comment: BTW, why are you doing it that way?

Comment: @ScaryWombat , I have three different sections and each section should upload a single file, so I have three forms in my JSP page and I am not passing the file through either java script or J query.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, the problem solved by giving different id's to file.